# about UICollectionView Horizontal Paging with pure code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In order to achieve auto Horizontal scrolling, I custom a collectionView with 100 sections, and there're 5 items in every section. And then add a NSTimer, the original position is set to the middle of collectionView(the 50th sections), it works at last. (ps: the collectionView is the headerView of a tableView!)

***However, when I scroll  it by myself, it can't be scrolled to the next page properly.*** It always appears two items(position is irregular), but I only wanna one instead.

(***Newest Progress:***

After setting `flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0f.` the margin of two items becomes regular(close to a unknown fixed value). And I found if I just finish launching the app and to scroll it by myself, it behaves normal. But if waiting the NSTimer runs and to scroll, it behaves the above what I have said. In a word, if there is no NSTimer, it behaves normal. Maybe there is something wrong with NSTimer...)

**Excepted:**

[image]

[image]

**Original Actually:**

[image]

[image]

**Newest Actually**

[image]

[image]

If I need override `scrollViewDidScroll:`, and how? Or pay attention to some attributes?  ***Is there something wrong with my NSTimer?***

**Some codes:**

```
**POChannelPageHeader.h**  (a UICollectionViewCell)

@class POChannelPageItem;

@interface POChannelPageHeader : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) POChannelPageItem *channelPageItem;
+ (UICollectionViewCell *)cellWithCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView;

**POChannelPageHeader.m**
@interface POChannelPageHeader ()
@property (weak, nonatomic)  UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic)  UIImageView *picView;
@end


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

        [self makeView];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark  custom cell
- (void)makeView
{
    UIImageView * picView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.picView = picView;
    self.picView.alpha = 0.1f;
    self.picView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.picView];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.titleLabel = titleLabel;
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.6f]];
    self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
}


#pragma mark layoutSubviews
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.picView.x = 0.0f;
    self.picView.y = 0.0f;
    self.picView.width = kScreenWidth ;
    self.picView.height = 0.4 * kScreenHeight;

    self.titleLabel.x = self.picView.x;
    self.titleLabel.width = kScreenWidth;
    CGFloat titleLabelPadding = 12.0f; 
    self.titleLabel.height = [NSString heightForText:self.titleLabel.text boundingRectWithWidth:TitleLabelWidth fontOfSize:15.0f] + titleLabelPadding;
    self.titleLabel.y = self.picView.height - self.titleLabel.height;

}

#pragma mark - setter
- (void)setChannelPageItem:(POChannelPageItem *)channelPageItem
{
    _channelPageItem = channelPageItem;
    self.picView.alpha = 0.1f;
    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2f]];
    [self.picView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_channelPageItem.imgsrc] placeholderImage:placeholderImage options:SDWebImageRetryFailed completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            self.picView.alpha = 1.0f;
        }];
    }];

    self.titleLabel.text = [@"  "  stringByAppendingString:_channelPageItem.title];

}




#import "POChannelPageViewController.h" ( a UITableViewController)

#define POChannelHeaderID     @"POChannelPageHeader"
#define POMaxSections         100
#define POChannelHeaderPages  5

@interface POChannelPageViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property (weak, nonatomic)  UICollectionView *headerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *headerNews;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIPageControl *headerPage;


@end



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self makeHeaderView]
}

- (void)makeHeaderView
{

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout= [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth, 0.4 * kScreenHeight);
    UICollectionView *headerView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth , 0.4 *kScreenHeight) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    headerView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    self.headerView = headerView;
    self.headerView.delegate = self;
    self.headerView.dataSource = self;
    self.headerView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    [self.headerView registerClass:[POChannelPageHeader class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:POChannelHeaderID];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView =self.headerView;

    // add PageControl
    UIPageControl *headerPage = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
    headerPage.x = kScreenWidth - 100.0f  + 2.0f; // little adjustment 
    headerPage.height = 37;
    headerPage.y =  self.headerView.height - headerPage.height +  5.0f;// little adjustment 
    headerPage.width = 100.0f;
    self.headerPage = headerPage;
    self.headerPage.numberOfPages = POChannelHeaderPages;
    self.headerPage.currentPage = 0;
    self.headerPage.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.headerPage.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.735 green:1.000 blue:0.300 alpha:1.000];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.hederPage];

    [self.headerView  scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:POMaxSections / 2] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:NO];

    [self addTimer];

}

#pragma mark - add Timer
- (void)addTimer
{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(nextPage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    self.timer = timer;

}

#pragma mark - remove Timer
- (void)removeTimer
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}

#pragma mark - resetIndexPath
- (NSIndexPath *)resetIndexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [[self.headerView indexPathsForVisibleItems] lastObject];

    NSIndexPath *currentIndexPathReset = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentIndexPath.item inSection:POMaxSections / 2];

    [self.headerView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:currentIndexPathReset atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:NO];
    return currentIndexPathReset;
}

- (void)nextPage
{
    NSIndexPath *currentIndexPathReset = [self resetIndexPath];

    NSInteger nextItem = currentIndexPathReset.item + 1;
    NSInteger nextSection = currentIndexPathReset.section;
    if (nextItem == self.headerNews.count) {
        nextItem = 0;
        nextSection++;
    }
    NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:nextItem inSection:nextSection];

    [self.headerView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.headerNews.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return POMaxSections;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    POChannelPageHeader *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:POChannelHeaderID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.channelPageItem = self.headerNews[indexPath.item];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark  - UICollectionViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
        [self removeTimer];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{

    if (scrollView == self.headerView) {
         [self addTimer];
    }


}



**// I'm not sure this method, because I study from a demo**
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  
{
    if(scrollView == self.tableView ){
        **// especially here!!!** 
     NSInteger page = (NSInteger)(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width + 0.5) % self.headerNews.count;
     self.headerPage.currentPage = page;

  } else if (scrollView ==self.tableView && scrollView.contentOffset.y ==0){

      [self addTimer];

}
```

Comment: You need: collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES.  And be sure than the collectionView.frame is equal than the collectionViewCell + inset in all direction.

Comment: @OnikIV : The pagingEnabled was set.  If there is a default inset when I don't  set it?

Comment: you need to put some code over here that how are you scrolling and setting the bounds for each image upon scroll.

Comment: @SandeepAggarwal  Thank your advice!  I have paste some related codes.

Comment: If you don't scroll by yourself by dragging, is it working correctly using timer alone?

Comment: YES!  At least the display is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain why did you create 100 section instead of one section with 100 items? Anyway I see 2 mistakes:
1) You have a full width picture and "inter item space", but you don't have a place on the screen for this space (in your case it is not inter item space, but right section inset or something else)
2) You have a right section inset, but you don't have a left

So if you will set initial position to first cell and swipes, you'll see a section inset on the screen. At the next swipe you will see small part of the previous cell, inset and next cell... In this way after 50 swipes you will see unpredictable screen offset.

I had paint a some way to solve your problem (sorry for my fotoshop's skill :D). In the picture black rect is screen, red - collection view, and green - cell. X is your space between cells. So you need to increase collection view width, depose it left, set left and right section insets with half value of this space.

[image]

Resulting in you will have a full screen width picture with inter item space, that you will see only while swiping.

**EDIT:** there is example project https://github.com/dimasv28/slider

Comment: I‘m a little dizzy. Could you please express it in my code or give a simple demo

Comment: I can't, bcs I don't understand what is exactly space between you sections/cells. Do you set it in storyboard? If you have 100 sections with 1 cell into them, you need to be sure, that there is no any spaces inside every section, then you can set equals left and right section insets (x/2 on my picture) etc.

Comment: You see that I create it by pure code without using  storyboard. Could you tell me how to set it in code?

Comment: Use `- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: I haven't set  any spaces  inside every section~

Comment: Then you need to understand at first, what is a black separator between you cells

Comment: In my case the value should be ? I haven't set any spaces inside every section~

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72469/discussion-between-aquarium-moose-and-elijah-lam).

Comment: After comparing my case with your demo, I have found the error and fixed it with the old way(100 sections with 1item)  : `flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0f`. The key is that  there is  a default minimumLineSpacing(10.0f) when you create collectionView with pure code,  and must reset it to 0.0f. Thank your demo!@aquarium_moose

Comment: Unluckily，I just found the above soultion only fixed some part. The margin of two items becomes regular(a fixed value). If there is no solutions at last, I'll take your tips!

Comment: `minimumLineSpacing` is a space between 2 lines :) but you have only one.. you need to find another reason of space between items\sections

Comment: I found if I just finish launching the app and to scroll it by myself, it behaves normal. But if waiting the NSTimer runs and to scroll, it behaves the above what I have said. In a word, if there is no NSTimer, it behaves normal. Maybe there is something wrong with NSTimer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72517/discussion-between-elijah-lam-and-aquarium-moose).

Comment: I have fixed it! It can perform perfect like a ads bar now. However, I can't find the origin of the error, because I change too much at the same time. I' m sure there is no another spacing need to be reset except `minimumLineSpacing`. I guess a inconspicuous  place is not properly or my simulator is abnormal. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a UIPageViewController for this? It seems like a much better fit for your problem. It's designed to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with UIPageViewController. And there, it is the headerView of a tableView. If I can use it?

Comment: UIPageViewController is a view controller that manages pages of content that you can make either slide one to the next,or use a page curl transition like iBooks. There is a sample program from Apple called PhotoScroller that demonstrates using it. (It does a lot of other stuff you don't need.) It used to be linked from the docs on UIPageViewController, but I can't find it there any more. I did find it on Apple's site through a google search though.

Comment: A UIPageViewController is a much better fit for what you are doing than a collection view.

Comment: If I can use it as the headerView of a tableView?  Because here the collectionView is the the headerView of a tableView instead of a controller.

Comment: You could make it work as the header of a table view but that might not be the best fit.